# Trying to center menu buttons

Tags: android

I'm trying to have a menu of 2 buttons vertically.  I set the layout to RelativeLayout .  The first button is centered by
   android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
which works.

when I tried to add the second button to be under the first button by
 android:layout_toBottomOf="@+id/menuat"
it gives me a error.

How would I center more then one button on the screen?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/backFeetGallery"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/menua"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:text="But A" 
  />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/menub"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_toBottomOf="@+id/menuat"
      android:text="But B" 
  />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You can try `LinearLayout` , see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189883/center-two-buttons-horizontally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`layout_toBottomOf` isn't a valid parameter. Use `layout_below` instead.

Here's the amended code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/backFeetGallery"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/menua"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:text="But A" 
  />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/menub"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_below="@+id/menua"
      android:text="But B" 
  />

</RelativeLayout>
```

By replacing this code you would get menub to be below menua

The full set of relative positions are:

```
android:layout_toLeftOf
android:layout_toRightOf
android:layout_above
android:layout_below
```